# Best way to load external URL into jQuery Mobile App

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

Im developing an jQuery Mobile App with Phonegap and Im looking for the best OS-Independent solution to load an external Webpage into the app while keeping the header/header-navigation.
I've tried it with an iFrame but that worked not that well (I just cant scroll right) btw. it isnt a mobile webpage which shall be loaded so I must be able to scroll in every direction.

Lib versions
jQuery 2.0.0
jQuery Mobile 1.3.1
Phonegap 2.9.0

can anyone help me ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is inAppBrowser in phone gap 2.9.0.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

I had used child browser plug in for the same requirement when used phone gap 2.2.0

Comment: well that was easy.. I think it was a typical case of RTFM =D. Thank You!